# Testing that a Python program maintains data consistency by simulating interruptions

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, consistency

I'm writing a Python program that needs to save data whilst guaranteeing data consistency, that is, if the program gets interrupted during the save (due to a power outage, for example), then it will not suffer from data loss or from data being left in an inconsistent state. How can I write a unit test that will simulate errors at different locations in the code, in order to then check if the data is still valid?

I can't limit myself to just writing `raise` or `assert` statements in my code that will activate during testing as:

1. I'd like to avoid that code bloat.
2. I need to simulate interruptions at low-level code positions and not just assume that interrupts will always happen in between high-level Python commands.

I was thinking of something like hijacking the Python interpreter itself but maybe there's a better way.

Comment: start in a separate process, terminate after a fixed delay(s), check data integrity?

Comment: @Marat Could be but will result in non-deterministic tests where you don't always interrupt at the same event (unless there's a way to use process time instead of wall clock time).

Comment: I'd say it is impossible to get deterministic breaking points without instrumenting the code, which you're trying to avoid